# Add character in .txt file in python

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I'm working on a python script that need from the user to add an argument on the command line to call the script. The script is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
  sys.exit("Error : argument expected.")

print("coucou")
a = ['SDK', 'DESKTOP', 'DFEM', 'COMMAND', 'TOK', 'DESKTOPONLY']
z = a.count(sys.argv[1]
if z == 0:
  sys.exit("Error : argument invalid.")

print (sys.argv[1])
```

and the error is

```
  File "./test.py", line 10
    if z == 0:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anybody help me ? :) I'm just starting python, and it's driving me crazy...

Comment: On the line before: `a = a.count(sys.argv[1]` should be  `a = a.count(sys.argv[1])`

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on the previous line. Also, why not use `argparse`? Then you get `--h` help magically, etc.

Comment: GOSH I was stuck during 40 min on that... thx guys^^